# UICollectionViewCell UILabel with NSMutableAttributedString attributedText slow to update & display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionview, nsmutableattributedstring

Using iOS 8.1.2 on iPad & iPhone. I have UICollectionViewCells which are created with initWithCoder: from a xib and displayed in a UICollectionView with

```
[_collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HomeFeedCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

The template xib cell contains a UILabel with default attributed text. The cell is also set up to use autolayout constraints.

When the cell is instantiated & updated with its data I call the following method to update the attributed text:

```
- (void)setLabelsForData:(NSDictionary*)dict_data {

    NSMutableAttributedString* attributedText_date = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self dateStringForTimestamp:[dict_data objectForKey:@"ts"]]];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attributedText_time = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self timeStringForTimestamp:[dict_data objectForKey:@"ts"]]];

    UIFont* font_date = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0];
    UIFont* font_time = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];

    [attributedText_date addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_date range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText_date.length)];
    [attributedText_time addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_time range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText_time.length)];

    dateLabel.attributedText = attributedText_date;
    timeLabel.attributedText = attributedText_time;

}
```

However when the UICollectionView is pushed modally, when the cells in view are initially displayed and each shows their UILabel's attributed text in its original xib default form for about 1 second before finally updating with the correct data & formatting. Once the UICollectionView has been shown though the UILables do not have this problem while scrolling through those cells and any new ones. Only initially on the visible ones upon the appearance of the UICollectionView.

I have tried:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[collectionView invalidateLayout];
```

at the end of the method. I have even put the whole method on the main thread hoping it was a thread issue, but no luck.

What could be causing the slow update of the UILabel?

Comment: If you're doing all this on a background thread, thats why... do it all on the main thread and it won't appear without text, albeit may be slow to present.

Comment: You shouldn't be recreating strings and fonts each reload though. Consider doing those things when you create the datasource instead of when filling out the collectionView.

Comment: Run the app through instruments with the time profiler to see where its really getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setLabelsForData:) withObject:dict_data waitUntilDone:NO];`

So as to run the whole method on the main thread. But it still does the same thing. That's a good point about calculating the strings as part of the datasource beforehand. I'll give that a try..

Comment: I suppose this sounds like the calls to update the collectionview are being called after the viewcontroller is presenting it's views. Even if you throw these calls on the mainQueue, it doesn't get run until after the VC is instantiated and presented. So, I would say to update the contents of the modally presented collection view before you actually end up presenting it (on a background queue though).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Which specific call needs to happen before the VC's `viewDidAppear:`, is it `[_collectionView reloadData];` or you mean `[self.view layoutSubviews];`?

Comment: Show the code that calls `setLabelsForData:`.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit late but seems that I have the same problem the easiest solution for me was to update the `UILabel` in 
`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
(this method is available in IOS 8 and up).

I also encounter the same problem with `UITableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```